# Neo4j Spring JSON

Tags: json, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

Imagine i have a Person node who has 3 hobbies

Peter -> Hockey

Peter -> Soccer

Peter -> Basketball

When i call it from string from

```
interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long>{

@Query("MATCH (p:Person)-[has:HAS_HOBBY]->(h:Hobby) RETURN p, has, h"
List<Person> find();
```

Then i have a `PersonService` method which calls `PersonRepostiry.find()`

And when i call this method from `PersonService` in controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String all(){
    return personService.find();
}
```

It all works perfectly, but when i access this localhost:8080/ i get json like this

```
{
    "person":"Peter",
    "hobbies":{
          "name":"hockey"
     }, {
          "name":"soccer"
     }, {
          "name":"basketball"
     }
}
```

but i would really like to get output like this

```
{
    "person":"Peter",
    "hobby": { "name":"hockey" }
}
{
    "person":"Peter",
    "hobby": { "name":"soccer" }
}
{
    "person":"Peter",
    "hobby": { "name":"basketball" }
}
```

EDIT:

```
@NodeEntity
class Person{
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    @RelationShip(type="HAS_HOBBY")
    public Set<Hobby> hobbies;

    public addHobby(Hobby hobby) { TODO.. }
}
```

Comment: its more "pseudo-code" i was writing it from memory

Comment: can you give the definition of your `Person` class ?

Comment: i just added it

Comment: And you don't want to change `public Set<Hobby> hobbies;` to `public Set<Hobby> hobby` ?

Comment: This wont solve my problem

Comment: Hooo sorry .... I was focused on the attribut name .. and not on the JSON data. My bad

Answer (score 1):

This type of JSON response creation could be done in your service or controller layer, iterating over what is returned from personService.find() and building a custom Map with the desired JSON shape.